# RemoteApp Drag-and-Drop

Tags: c#, file, drag-and-drop, remoteapp

I successfully managed to implement file drag-and-drop onto my Winforms application.

However, when running it as a RemoteApp, drag-and-drop is disabled.

Is there a way around, using a "copy" of the dragged file in the clipboard (as copy-paste works) onto the host machine, say in the `DragOver` event?

If so, what are the related security issues, if any?

Answer (score 0):

It requires first that users have a mapped drive that is accessible from both their desktop and the RDS servers.  Next, publish explorer.exe as a RemoteApp.  Change parameters to use this only and set the path of the mapped drive (and any subfolder within) that you'd like to have them drag and drop from.  We had to do this for a customer who uses attachments in Quickbooks.  I created a RemoteApp mapped to a scanned documents folder on their network so they could drag and drop PDF files into Quickbooks.

Comment: Welcome to SO Matt! Are you able to provide any clear and useful code to accompany your answer?